# Cannot "add to address book" in thunderbird on mac. Know a workaround?

Tags: thunderbird, osx-mountain-lion

Runing TB 24.5.0 on Mac 10.8.5. I configure TB so that File-"Use Mac OS X Address Book" is not selected. Can open Address Book and see addresses in "COllected Addresses" & create New contact there.
But in TB cannot "add to address book". I click on star to right of email address or ctrl-click correspondent and "add to address book". Nothing happens.

But correspondent should be added to (some) address book.

This is a major inconvenience because I use the address book to distinguish between junk mail from people who I do not know and good mail from people who I do know.

Currently the only way for me to add anybody to the address book is to do so by hand, one at a time in "collected addresses".

I welcome any work around that would let me add somebody to an address book with a single click.

Thanks